# Comma separated when same id rows data into in one row data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I need help regarding the screenshot I have attached.

**Scenario:** one user can have multiple roles. So here in the screenshot, the same userid has different rowid and rolename. I want to show them in a single row as I have shown in the screenshot as the desired result.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id, 
    U.UserId, U.FirstName, U.LastName, 
    (U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName) AS FullName, 
    u.email, u.PhoneNumber, u.Username,
    COALESCE(RR.RoleId, PU.RoleId, sbr.RoleId) AS RoleId,
    COALESCE(RR.RoleName, R.RoleName,sbr.RoleName) AS RoleName,
    COALESCE(RR.RoleType, R.RoleType,sbr.RoleType) AS RoleType, u.[Image]
FROM
    [User] U
LEFT JOIN
    PlatformUser PU ON PU.UserId = u.UserId AND PU.IsDeleted <> 1
LEFT JOIN
    Role R ON R.RoleId = PU.RoleId 
LEFT JOIN
    UserToSchool UTS ON UTS.UserId = u.UserId AND UTS.IsDeleted <> 1
LEFT JOIN
    Role RR ON RR.RoleId = UTS.RoleId
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.UserToSchoolBranch usb ON usb.UserId = u.UserId AND usb.IsDeleted <> 1
LEFT JOIN  
    dbo.Role sbr ON sbr.RoleId = usb.RoleId
WHERE
    (RR.RoleType = @pRoleType OR R.RoleType = @pRoleType OR sbr.RoleType = @pRoleType) 
    AND ISNULL(u.isdeleted, 0) <> 1
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand why 321 is in the output instead of 323? Is there some relation here between user 1 and user 3046 that isn't obvious to us? Also, please always specify what version of SQL Server you're using... there are only 9 major versions to choose from, and some versions have relevant functionality that others don't. Just saying "SQL Server" is like me going to a junk yard and saying I need a steering wheel for a BMW. They're going to need to pull my teeth in order to give me the help I'm asking for.

Comment: In SQL Server 2017 and later you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to easily concatenate rows. In earlier versions you need a complex query. Which version are you using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos First of all thanks for Quick reply.scenerio is one user can be assigned multiple roles please see the userid 3046 have two roles which is in two rows.i have two version installed sqlserver 2017 and sql server 2008R2  but i work on 2017.

Comment: @OlgaRomantsova due to low reputation i cannot vote and not even check the answer...

Answer (score 1):

If your query AS cte, then you can use `FOR XML PATH()` to get one row:

```
with cte as
(
    your query
)
select distinct UserId, FirstName, LastName, FullName, email, PhoneNumber, Username, 

    stuff((select Concat(',',RoleId) 
    from cte cte1
    where cte1.UserId = cte2.UserId 
    for xml path('')),1,1,'') All_roles_Id,
   
    stuff((select Concat(',',RoleName) 
    from cte cte1
    where cte1.UserId = cte2.UserId 
    for xml path('')),1,1,'') All_roles_name

from cte cte2
```

Or you can try to use `String_AGG` (SQl server 2017):

```
   select UserId, FirstName, LastName, FullName, email, PhoneNumber, Username, 
   string_agg(RoleId,',') All_roles_Id,
   string_agg(RoleName,',') All_roles_Name
   from cte
   group by UserId, FirstName, LastName, FullName, email, PhoneNumber, Username
```

Comment: ManDark, please tell. do you try it?

Comment: Yes i tried but not as i expected..because this function string_agg requires group by clause i cannot use it with that.

Comment: what do you mean? within group option?

Comment: if i use this function string_agg this force me to use group by clause with this

Comment: ManDark, but i write 2 queries..in second query this function is present and also there's group by...

Comment: thanks It works thank you soo much both queries works.Thanks Once again

Comment: I wish i can but due to low reputation i am not able to accept it sorry for that but your both queries worked